# What would you expect of this C++ expression?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, syntax, ternary-operator

```
  bool bSwitch  = true;
  double dSum = 1 + bSwitch?1:2;
```

So "dSum" is:

a)=1 
b)=2 
c)=3

The result  is just rediculous and i got bashed for it...

I'm using VS2008 -> "Microsoft (R) 32-Bit C/C++-Optimierungscompiler Version 15.00.21022.08 für 80x86"

Comment: For the record, every C++ compiler will do the same. A rule of thumb: multiplication and division before addition and subtraction; everything else gets parens.

Comment: Note to self: use as many parentheses as you can when dealing with the ternary operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`operator+` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), than the ternary operator `?:`.

So, this is equivalent to

```
double dSum = ( 1 + bSwitch ) ? 1 : 2;
```

Thus, you have `dSum == 1`.

Comment: Spasibo Kiril! Ja ponjal 4to oblagalsja ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's a precedence thing isn't it.

```
bool bSwitch  = true;
double dSum = (1 + bSwitch)?1:2;
```

`dSum` will be 1.0

Would have been easier to spot with sensible spacing around the operators.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect `1.`, because the `+` operator takes precedence over the ternary operator. So the expression is read as

```
double dSum = (1 + bSwitch) ? 1:2;
```

and `1 + bSwitch` is non-zero, so it evaluates as `true`.

See [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 1):

A warning, obviously, but I use a true compiler:

```
void foo() {
  bool bSwitch  = true;
  double dSum = 1 + bSwitch?1:2;
}
```

gives:

```
$ clang++ -fsyntax-only test.cpp
test.cpp:3:28: warning: operator '?:' has lower precedence than '+'; '+' will be evaluated first [-Wparentheses]
  double dSum = 1 + bSwitch?1:2;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~^
test.cpp:3:28: note: place parentheses around the '+' expression to silence this warning
  double dSum = 1 + bSwitch?1:2;
                           ^
                (          )
test.cpp:3:28: note: place parentheses around the '?:' expression to evaluate it first
  double dSum = 1 + bSwitch?1:2;
                           ^
                    (          )
1 warning generated.
```

And yes, I gave en entire command line, it's **on** by default.